# Particle-in-cell (PIC) code Virtual Laser Plasma Lab (VLPL)

Tags: simulations, laser, software, plasma-physics, x-rays

I am writing a simulation code to model betatron X rays produced by electrons accelerated using laser wakefield acceleration (LWFA). I have heard about 3D PIC (Particle-in-Cell) code VLPL (Virtual Laser Plasma Lab) developed by Max-Planck-Institutes for Quantum Optics in 1999. Since, some hybrid codes appeared.

Do you know where I could get some 3D PIC VLPL source code?

Comment: Have you contacted any of the authors? That would be a good place to start.

Comment: It's in progress.

Comment: @Joelafrite I'm working with PIC models in relation with particle acceleration in plasmas, if you find any interesting 3D PIC code would you be so kind to tell me about it? I'll need it soon too. Thank you!

Comment: @manuel91 I did not find VLPL source code but I found [iPic3D](https://github.com/CmPA/iPic3D) on GitHub.

Answer (score 2):

i think PIConGPU is the best choice for simulation of laser plasma interaction especially for large scale plasma. the VLPL code has been written by Prof. Pukhov's group and isn't open source. you have to contact to him or his coworkers to get the code. if you have enough time like two or three years for your simulations, you can write your own code by yourself.

Answer (score 1):

In my experience (PhD student working on laser plasma interaction experiments) these PIC codes are pretty closely guarded by their creators.  There are a few out there, for example OSIRIS, VORPAL, and TurboWave in addition to VLPL.  Of these I think only VORPAL is commercially available (through Tech-X) and the others you would need to contact the groups that maintain code.  Cheers and welcome to the club!

Comment: To be fair, the "close guarded"-ness of so-called "public" codes are not limited to PIC codes.

Answer (score 1):

[PIConGPU](https://github.com/ComputationalRadiationPhysics/picongpu) is a fully open source PIC code.

It even includes features beyond the standard PIC cycle such as online generation of far field radiation using Lienard Wiechert Potentials, photon generation via QED synchrotron radiation and bremsstrahlung, classical radiation reaction and advanced field ionization methods.

It further has a large collection of [in-situ plugins](https://github.com/ComputationalRadiationPhysics/picongpu/wiki/PIConGPU-Plugins) and [CPU support](https://github.com/ComputationalRadiationPhysics/picongpu-alpaka) in case you do not have access to GPU hardware.

Comment: Since the original question requested PIC code, I'm not sure this completely applies, but could be useful to somebody else.